# Git commit by local config instead of global

Tags: git

my repo config is below

```
git config --local --list
user.name=my
user.email=my email
```

```
git config --global --list
user.name=other
user.email=other's email
```

When I made a commit, it showed other's name and email instead of my name. So, how could I make local config(my config) into default.

Comment: Local config overrides global config by design. What you describe is unexpected. Can you double-check?

Comment: Are you running the --local command in the projects folder? What are you using to commit the changes? Some GUI? Check that it doesn't have some own configuration.

Comment: @RomainValeri yes, result same with before.

Comment: @martin.malek commited by git cz tool, probably caused by it.